# Memcache::get not working with array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, memcached

I am trying to test the `multi_get` functionality of memcached client in PHP, and I know that

```
array Memcache::get ( array $keys [, array &$flags ] )
```

is available.

```
00000001 <?php
00000002     function rand01()
00000003     {   // auxiliary function
00000004          // returns random number with flat distribution from 0 to 1
00000005         return (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax();
00000006     }
00000007     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
00000008     $mc=new Memcached();
00000009     $mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_DISTRIBUTION,Memcached::DISTRIBUTION_CONSISTENT);
00000010     $mc->setOption(Memcached::OPT_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS,true);
00000011     echo "return value of addServer<br>";
00000012     var_dump($mc->addServer("mc1",11211));
00000013     var_dump($mc->addServer("mc2",11211));
00000014     var_dump($mc->addServer("mc3",11211));
00000015     echo "<br>";
00000016     $mc->set('00010111222',"testval");
00000017     $mc->set('00010333444',"testval");
00000018     echo "<br>";
00000019     var_dump($mc->get(array('00010111222', '00010333444')));
00000020     var_dump($mc->getResultCode());
00000023 ?>
```

But it gives me the following output:

```
   return value of addServer
   bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)
   Warning: Memcached::get() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/memcache.php on line 19
   NULL int(0)
```

Which means that the servers are successfully added, but `get()` in line 19 gives a warning for parameter being an array and the returned object is NULL. The return code is 0 which means that query was successful, and keys are present in memcached since I am setting them in line 16 and 17. Is there something I am doing wrong or is this a bug in PHP::Memcache?

Comment: As a user with 1000+ reputation, I would expect at the very least that you would shown the code on line 39 on which it errors. But out of respect I wont downvote. However if you mean line 39 is actually `00000019` I would suggest you abide by the error message.

Comment: Ah yes, the line numbers are messed up. It is actually line 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `Memcache` vs. `Memcached` issue.

`Memcached::get` accepts only a string as the first argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.get.php

`Memcache::get` is the method that accepts a string or an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php

You can accomplish the same result as looping through the array and calling `Memcached::get($key)` for each value.

Comment: I think you are right, I don't know how I missed that. There is `Memcached::getMulti()`  for `Memcached` . Thanks.